# Why are there 2 calls to the root of my site in firebug's Net panel

Tags: performance

I am trying to diagnose performance problems on a website. The Net panel in Firebug is showing 2 calls to the site root that take place early in the process. Each call takes about 1.5 seconds of "waiting", then about 20ms of "receiving".

I'd like to know why there are 2 of these calls, but it is not obvious from the panel. Can anyone suggest a reason, or even a tool that would help track down the cause?

Comment: A screenshot of what you see in Firebug could really help. Feel free to redact anything irrelevant.

Comment: You can also use Chrome's developer tools to create a waterfall graph. This often tells you exactly what is going on.